# Why does Selenium not click the desired button in Chrome headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following Python script whose purpose is to copy the entire Contract Source Code from https://bscscan.com/address/0xf811e41dc5271814ceb9aaf4f148478d5c6a0134#code using the "Copy source code to clipboard" button, located below the "Outline" and "More Options" buttons.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://bscscan.com/address/0xf811e41dc5271814ceb9aaf4f148478d5c6a0134#code')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/button'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/a[1]')
    )
).click()

driver.quit()
```

`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/button'))).click()`
is used to click an "allow cookies" pop-up which blocks the button I want when the page opens.

When running in headless mode, which is enabled using `options.add_argument("--headless")` I don't get an error but the text is not copied. When I comment out `options.add_argument("--headless")` and run the code with the normal window, the text is copied.

I plan to run this script in the background to scrape contract information from multiple cryptocurrency tokens, so being able to run it in headless mode is important.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should set the window size in headless mode, this will make your headless session to be similar to the regular session run.
Also, you should improve your locators.
Let me know if this works better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://bscscan.com/address/0xf811e41dc5271814ceb9aaf4f148478d5c6a0134#code')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='btnCookie']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.justify-content-end a.js-clipboard "))).click()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: This achieved the same result. The script works while not in headless mode--the button is clicked and the entire source code text from the page is copied to my clipboard. However, when headless mode is used, the source code text is not copied to the clipboard, even though there are no errors.

Comment: Can you please try to add a short delay after the last click before quitting the driver?

Comment: Added a ```time.sleep(5)``` before ```driver.quit()```, no change in the results.

Comment: Thanks! `window-size=1920,1080` helped while `start-maximized` didn't let do it in **headless** mode

Answer (score 1):

Try using this one:

`driver.set_window_size(2560, 1440)` (or whatever resolution you're using)

Out of all these options: `options.add_argument("window-size=2560,1440")`, `options.add_argument("--window-size=2560,1440")`, `options.add_argument("start-maximized")`, `driver.maximize_window()` this is the only one that works for clicking the cookie button with headless for me.

Answer (score 0):

To print the desired text you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.headless = True
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get("https://bscscan.com/address/0xf811e41dc5271814ceb9aaf4f148478d5c6a0134#code")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#btnCookie"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ace_layer.ace_text-layer"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.headless = True
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get("https://bscscan.com/address/0xf811e41dc5271814ceb9aaf4f148478d5c6a0134#code")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='btnCookie']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ace_layer ace_text-layer']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Alternative

To click on the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) with `data-original-title` set as *`Copy source code to clipboard`* and to print to the console you can use the [**clipboard**](https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/0.0.4/) module as follows:

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import clipboard

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://bscscan.com/address/0xf811e41dc5271814ceb9aaf4f148478d5c6a0134#code")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#btnCookie"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-original-title='Copy source code to clipboard']"))).click()
print(clipboard.paste())
```

Console Output:

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at BscScan.com on 2021-11-21
*/

// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }
}

/**
 * BEP20 standard interface.
 */
interface IBEP20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function getOwner() external view returns (address);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

abstract contract Auth {
    address internal owner;
    mapping (address => bool) internal authorizations;

    constructor(address _owner) {
        owner = _owner;
        authorizations[_owner] = true;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(isOwner(msg.sender), "!OWNER"); _;
    }

    modifier authorized() {
        require(isAuthorized(msg.sender), "!AUTHORIZED"); _;
    }

    function authorize(address adr) public onlyOwner {
        authorizations[adr] = true;
    }

    function unauthorize(address adr) public onlyOwner {
        authorizations[adr] = false;
    }

    function isOwner(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return account == owner;
    }

    function isAuthorized(address adr) public view returns (bool) {
        return authorizations[adr];
    }

    function transferOwnership(address payable adr) public onlyOwner {
        owner = adr;
        authorizations[adr] = true;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(adr);
    }

    event OwnershipTransferred(address owner);
}

interface IDEXFactory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}

interface IDEXRouter {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);

    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);

    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;

    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable;

    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}

interface IDividendDistributor {
    function setDistributionCriteria(uint256 _minPeriod, uint256 _minDistribution) external;
    function setShare(address shareholder, uint256 amount) external;
    function deposit() external payable;
    function process(uint256 gas) external;
}

contract DividendDistributor is IDividendDistributor {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address _token;

    struct Share {
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 totalExcluded;
        uint256 totalRealised;
    }

    IBEP20 RWRD = IBEP20(0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56);
    address WBNB = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
    IDEXRouter router;

    address[] shareholders;
    mapping (address => uint256) shareholderIndexes;
    mapping (address => uint256) shareholderClaims;

    mapping (address => Share) public shares;

    uint256 public totalShares;
    uint256 public totalDividends;
    uint256 public totalDistributed;
    uint256 public dividendsPerShare;
    uint256 public dividendsPerShareAccuracyFactor = 10 ** 36;

    uint256 public minPeriod = 45 * 60;
    uint256 public minDistribution = 1 * (10 ** 19);

    uint256 currentIndex;

    bool initialized;
    modifier initialization() {
        require(!initialized);
        _;
        initialized = true;
    }

    modifier onlyToken() {
        require(msg.sender == _token); _;
    }

    constructor (address _router) {
        router = _router != address(0)
            ? IDEXRouter(_router)
            : IDEXRouter(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
        _token = msg.sender;
    }

    function setDistributionCriteria(uint256 _minPeriod, uint256 _minDistribution) external override onlyToken {
        minPeriod = _minPeriod;
        minDistribution = _minDistribution;
    }

    function setShare(address shareholder, uint256 amount) external override onlyToken {
        if(shares[shareholder].amount > 0){
            distributeDividend(shareholder);
        }

        if(amount > 0 && shares[shareholder].amount == 0){
            addShareholder(shareholder);
        }else if(amount == 0 && shares[shareholder].amount > 0){
            removeShareholder(shareholder);
        }

        totalShares = totalShares.sub(shares[shareholder].amount).add(amount);
        shares[shareholder].amount = amount;
        shares[shareholder].totalExcluded = getCumulativeDividends(shares[shareholder].amount);
    }

    function deposit() external payable override onlyToken {
        uint256 balanceBefore = RWRD.balanceOf(address(this));

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = WBNB;
        path[1] = address(RWRD);

        router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: msg.value}(
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        uint256 amount = RWRD.balanceOf(address(this)).sub(balanceBefore);

        totalDividends = totalDividends.add(amount);
        dividendsPerShare = dividendsPerShare.add(dividendsPerShareAccuracyFactor.mul(amount).div(totalShares));
    }

    function process(uint256 gas) external override onlyToken {
        uint256 shareholderCount = shareholders.length;

        if(shareholderCount == 0) { return; }

        uint256 gasUsed = 0;
        uint256 gasLeft = gasleft();

        uint256 iterations = 0;

        while(gasUsed < gas && iterations < shareholderCount) {
            if(currentIndex >= shareholderCount){
                currentIndex = 0;
            }

            if(shouldDistribute(shareholders[currentIndex])){
                distributeDividend(shareholders[currentIndex]);
            }

            gasUsed = gasUsed.add(gasLeft.sub(gasleft()));
            gasLeft = gasleft();
            currentIndex++;
            iterations++;
        }
    }

    function shouldDistribute(address shareholder) internal view returns (bool) {
        return shareholderClaims[shareholder] + minPeriod < block.timestamp
                && getUnpaidEarnings(shareholder) > minDistribution;
    }

    function distributeDividend(address shareholder) internal {
        if(shares[shareholder].amount == 0){ return; }

        uint256 amount = getUnpaidEarnings(shareholder);
        if(amount > 0){
            totalDistributed = totalDistributed.add(amount);
            RWRD.transfer(shareholder, amount);
            shareholderClaims[shareholder] = block.timestamp;
            shares[shareholder].totalRealised = shares[shareholder].totalRealised.add(amount);
            shares[shareholder].totalExcluded = getCumulativeDividends(shares[shareholder].amount);
        }
    }

    function claimDividend() external {
        distributeDividend(msg.sender);
    }

    function getUnpaidEarnings(address shareholder) public view returns (uint256) {
        if(shares[shareholder].amount == 0){ return 0; }

        uint256 shareholderTotalDividends = getCumulativeDividends(shares[shareholder].amount);
        uint256 shareholderTotalExcluded = shares[shareholder].totalExcluded;

        if(shareholderTotalDividends <= shareholderTotalExcluded){ return 0; }

        return shareholderTotalDividends.sub(shareholderTotalExcluded);
    }

    function getCumulativeDividends(uint256 share) internal view returns (uint256) {
        return share.mul(dividendsPerShare).div(dividendsPerShareAccuracyFactor);
    }

    function addShareholder(address shareholder) internal {
        shareholderIndexes[shareholder] = shareholders.length;
        shareholders.push(shareholder);
    }

    function removeShareholder(address shareholder) internal {
        shareholders[shareholderIndexes[shareholder]] = shareholders[shareholders.length-1];
        shareholderIndexes[shareholders[shareholders.length-1]] = shareholderIndexes[shareholder];
        shareholders.pop();
    }
}

contract CASHSLOTHTOKEN is IBEP20, Auth {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address WBNB = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
    address DEAD = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    address ZERO = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

    string constant _name = "CashSlothToken";
    string constant _symbol = "CSH";
    uint8 constant _decimals = 2;

    uint256 _totalSupply = 1 * 10**15 * 10**_decimals;

    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = _totalSupply * 3 / 100;
    uint256 public _maxWalletToken = _totalSupply * 5 / 100;

    mapping (address => uint256) _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) _allowances;

    bool public blacklistMode = true;
    mapping (address => bool) public isBlacklisted;


    mapping (address => bool) isFeeExempt;
    mapping (address => bool) isTxLimitExempt;
    mapping (address => bool) isTimelockExempt;
    mapping (address => bool) isDividendExempt;

    uint256 public liquidityFee    = 2;
    uint256 public reflectionFee   = 6;
    uint256 public marketingFee    = 5;
    uint256 public teamFee         = 1;
    uint256 public burnFee         = 1;
    uint256 public totalFee        = marketingFee + reflectionFee + liquidityFee + teamFee + burnFee;
    uint256 public feeDenominator  = 100;

    uint256 public deadBlocks = 0;
    uint256 public launchedAt = 0;
    uint256 public sellMultiplier  = 113;

    address public autoLiquidityReceiver;
    address public marketingFeeReceiver;
    address public teamFeeReceiver;
    address public burnFeeReceiver;

    uint256 targetLiquidity = 99;
    uint256 targetLiquidityDenominator = 100;

    IDEXRouter public router;
    address public pair;

    bool public tradingOpen = false;

    DividendDistributor public distributor;
    uint256 distributorGas = 500000;

    bool public buyCooldownEnabled = false;
    uint8 public cooldownTimerInterval = 60;
    mapping (address => uint) private cooldownTimer;

    bool public swapEnabled = true;
    uint256 public swapThreshold = _totalSupply * 8 / 10000;
    bool inSwap;
    modifier swapping() { inSwap = true; _; inSwap = false; }

    constructor () Auth(msg.sender) {
        router = IDEXRouter(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
        pair = IDEXFactory(router.factory()).createPair(WBNB, address(this));
        _allowances[address(this)][address(router)] = uint256(-1);

        distributor = new DividendDistributor(address(router));

        isFeeExempt[msg.sender] = true;
        isTxLimitExempt[msg.sender] = true;

        isTimelockExempt[msg.sender] = true;
        isTimelockExempt[DEAD] = true;
        isTimelockExempt[address(this)] = true;

        isDividendExempt[pair] = true;
        isDividendExempt[address(this)] = true;
        isDividendExempt[DEAD] = true;

        autoLiquidityReceiver = DEAD;
        marketingFeeReceiver = 0xEE09d19caB47E66A957e70d5e186ff9448f0d987;
        teamFeeReceiver = 0x277BdadF7A82Ab1a9C5Cac664abfdF748aFF3486;
        burnFeeReceiver = DEAD;

        _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

    receive() external payable { }

    function totalSupply() external view override returns (uint256) { return _totalSupply; }
    function decimals() external pure override returns (uint8) { return _decimals; }
    function symbol() external pure override returns (string memory) { return _symbol; }
    function name() external pure override returns (string memory) { return _name; }
    function getOwner() external view override returns (address) { return owner; }
    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) { return _balances[account]; }
    function allowance(address holder, address spender) external view override returns (uint256) { return _allowances[holder][spender]; }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _allowances[msg.sender][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function approveMax(address spender) external returns (bool) {
        return approve(spender, uint256(-1));
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external override returns (bool) {
        return _transferFrom(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external override returns (bool) {
        if(_allowances[sender][msg.sender] != uint256(-1)){
            _allowances[sender][msg.sender] = _allowances[sender][msg.sender].sub(amount, "Insufficient Allowance");
        }

        return _transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function setMaxWalletPercent_base1000(uint256 maxWallPercent_base1000) external onlyOwner() {
        _maxWalletToken = (_totalSupply * maxWallPercent_base1000 ) / 1000;
    }
    function setMaxTxPercent_base1000(uint256 maxTXPercentage_base1000) external onlyOwner() {
        _maxTxAmount = (_totalSupply * maxTXPercentage_base1000 ) / 1000;
    }

    function setTxLimit(uint256 amount) external authorized {
        _maxTxAmount = amount;
    }


    function _transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal returns (bool) {
        if(inSwap){ return _basicTransfer(sender, recipient, amount); }

        if(!authorizations[sender] && !authorizations[recipient]){
            require(tradingOpen,"Trading not open yet");
        }

        // Blacklist
        if(blacklistMode){
            require(!isBlacklisted[sender] && !isBlacklisted[recipient],"Blacklisted");
        }


        if (!authorizations[sender] && recipient != address(this)  && recipient != address(DEAD) && recipient != pair && recipient != marketingFeeReceiver && recipient != teamFeeReceiver  && recipient != autoLiquidityReceiver && recipient != burnFeeReceiver){
            uint256 heldTokens = balanceOf(recipient);
            require((heldTokens + amount) <= _maxWalletToken,"Total Holding is currently limited, you can not buy that much.");}

        if (sender == pair &&
            buyCooldownEnabled &&
            !isTimelockExempt[recipient]) {
            require(cooldownTimer[recipient] < block.timestamp,"Please wait for 1min between two buys");
            cooldownTimer[recipient] = block.timestamp + cooldownTimerInterval;
        }

        // Checks max transaction limit
        checkTxLimit(sender, amount);

        if(shouldSwapBack()){ swapBack(); }

        //Exchange tokens
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "Insufficient Balance");

        uint256 amountReceived = (!shouldTakeFee(sender) || !shouldTakeFee(recipient)) ? amount : takeFee(sender, amount,(recipient == pair));
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amountReceived);

        // Dividend tracker
        if(!isDividendExempt[sender]) {
            try distributor.setShare(sender, _balances[sender]) {} catch {}
        }

        if(!isDividendExempt[recipient]) {
            try distributor.setShare(recipient, _balances[recipient]) {} catch {}
        }

        try distributor.process(distributorGas) {} catch {}

        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amountReceived);
        return true;
    }

    function _basicTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal returns (bool) {
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "Insufficient Balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function checkTxLimit(address sender, uint256 amount) internal view {
        require(amount <= _maxTxAmount || isTxLimitExempt[sender], "TX Limit Exceeded");
    }

  ...
  ...

    // enable cooldown between trades
    function cooldownEnabled(bool _status, uint8 _interval) public onlyOwner {
        buyCooldownEnabled = _status;
        cooldownTimerInterval = _interval;
    }

    function swapBack() internal swapping {
        uint256 dynamicLiquidityFee = isOverLiquified(targetLiquidity, targetLiquidityDenominator) ? 0 : liquidityFee;
        uint256 amountToLiquify = swapThreshold.mul(dynamicLiquidityFee).div(totalFee).div(2);
        uint256 amountToSwap = swapThreshold.sub(amountToLiquify);

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = WBNB;

        uint256 balanceBefore = address(this).balance;

        router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amountToSwap,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        uint256 amountBNB = address(this).balance.sub(balanceBefore);

        uint256 totalBNBFee = totalFee.sub(dynamicLiquidityFee.div(2));

        uint256 amountBNBLiquidity = amountBNB.mul(dynamicLiquidityFee).div(totalBNBFee).div(2);
        uint256 amountBNBReflection = amountBNB.mul(reflectionFee).div(totalBNBFee);
        uint256 amountBNBMarketing = amountBNB.mul(marketingFee).div(totalBNBFee);
        uint256 amountBNBTeam = amountBNB.mul(teamFee).div(totalBNBFee);

        try distributor.deposit{value: amountBNBReflection}() {} catch {}
        (bool tmpSuccess,) = payable(marketingFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBMarketing, gas: 30000}("");
        (tmpSuccess,) = payable(teamFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBTeam, gas: 30000}("");

        // only to supress warning msg
        tmpSuccess = false;

        if(amountToLiquify > 0){
            router.addLiquidityETH{value: amountBNBLiquidity}(
                address(this),
                amountToLiquify,
                0,
                0,
                autoLiquidityReceiver,
                block.timestamp
            );
            emit AutoLiquify(amountBNBLiquidity, amountToLiquify);
        }
    }
...  
...    
// ~by @monkey_shanti
```

Comment: Unfortunately, scraping the source code from the "ace_layer ace_text-layer" only obtains the lines of the source code which are on screen when the page is opened. I've tried this approach using beautifulsoup, only to find that I need to interact with the page in some way, hence my need for selenium. An option could be to automatically scroll through the source code, copying it line by line, but simply using the button to copy the entire thing would be much simpler. Do you know a solution that allows me to click the button while in headless mode?

Comment: @swagman Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: For some reason this does not work when headless mode is used. No errors are thrown, the text just isn't copied to the clipboard.

Comment: @swagman What do you mean by _does not work when headless mode is used_? You just need to add `import clipboard` and use this updated code block in place of the previous code block with all the options of the first code block (including headless) intact. Works perfectly at my end.

Comment: I'm using your exact code with the only change being the location of the webdriver, so I've removed ```from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
``` and ```service=s, ``` from ```driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)```. The desired text still doesn't print to the console. Instead, whatever was previously on the clipboard is printed. So when I run the code, the source code that I want isn't being copied to the clipboard. I'm not sure why this is. I'm using selenium 4.1.0 on Windows x64.

Comment: if at all using _selenium 4.1.0_, why removing `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service`  and `service=s`? Given the full code. Check now.

Comment: Added ```from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service```, ```s = Service('C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe')```, and ```driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)```. C:\\webdrivers\\ is the location of my webdriver, though it is already an environment variable and the script works without passing the service as an argument. No change in results, the source code is not copied to the clipboard.

Comment: What does `print()` prints? Ensure that you don't have copied data within the clipboard.

Comment: The only print statement is ```print(clipboard.paste())```. As a test, I first typed "test string" onto a notepad document and copied it. Then I ran the code with all lines commented out except ```print(clipboard.paste())```. "test string" was printed to the console, as expected. I then ran the code with all lines uncommented, without using headless mode. The source code that I desired was printed to the console. Finally, I re-copied "test string" and ran the code using headless mode. "test string" was outputted to the clipboard instead of the source code I was expecting.

Comment: You need to empty the clipboard before you start your test.

Comment: Did not work, no change in results. Cleared the clipboard using ```from ctypes import windll
if windll.user32.OpenClipboard(None):
    windll.user32.EmptyClipboard()
    windll.user32.CloseClipboard()```